# how i can rewrite url with my page title

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have page www.mysite.com/more.php?book=1
and I want create link like www.mysite.com/book-title.html
How I can do that?

In my page www.mysite.com/more.php?book=1 I generating url like this

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE id_book={$_GET['book']}");
while ($rw = mysql_fetch_object($res)){ 
    $title = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $rw->title)).'.html';
    }
```

and I have $title, but I dont know how I can use this in mod rewrite in .htaccess to get url 
www.mysite.com/book-title.html

I hope I managed to explain what I want to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please tell me that is example code and not real code or you are ripe for SQL injection

Comment: This example only. Thank you for your concern :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure your post titles (i.e. the URL-encoded versions) are unique. You can then set up your .htaccess using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ more.php?book=$1
```

And ensure your PHP script uses [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to avoid SQL injection:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my_db;host=127.0.0.1', 'user', 'password');
$statement = $db->prepare("select * from book where BOOK_NAME = :book");
$statement->execute(array(':book' => $_GET['book']));
$row = $statement->fetch();
```

Comment: My URL encoded version is unique, but I have a problem that I pass the value of $ title in htacces. My web page has generated www.mysite.com/more.php?book=1...2...3...4 ...

In page I create a user friendly url web-title.html and it's variable $ title
The problem is how to replace www.mysite.com/more.php?book=1...2...3...4 ...
  with www.mysite.com / book-title.html

Comment: Instead of passing in the Book ID in the URL, you can pass in the title (so that it looks like `/book-title.html`). All you have to do is search for the book title in your MySQL rather than the ID. Look at the statement in my code, and change it based on the column for book titles